# get response/result after submitting file to url

Tags: php, response

I'm trying to submit a file to a REST API url and need to get the response/result from this process. I'm trying to send it to another php and display the result but nothing. If it could display in the same php page then even better. How am i suppose to do that?

```
<?php
session_start();
// Start the session
$responseURL = "http://my-site.com/responseform.php";
$url = 'https://api-to-validate-file.com/api/validate';
$header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data','Authorization: apikey=0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f');
$fields = array('filename' => '@' . $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][0]);
$token = 'NfxoS9oGjA6MiArPtwg4aR3Cp4ygAbNA2uv6Gg4m';

$resource = curl_init();
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'apiToken=' . $token);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($resource));
///echo 'The body of the response is ' . $result;
curl_close($resource);
?>

<form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="filename" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    <input type="hidden" name="RespURL" value="<?= $responseURL ?>"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: try submitting the request manually and see what is returned.

Comment: Try testing the endpoint with client software like INSOMNIA or POSTMAN

Comment: The point is to show a result/response on the same (or another) php page. I did try with postman, but that doesn't help display the response on another page.